# Drum Rack in Ableton won't play sound

Tags: ableton-live

I have added a drum rack, but it won't play any sound. How do I fix this?

[image: Ableton Screenshot]

Comment: https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/instrument-drum-and-effect-racks/